# opencv compiled in 64 bit run in 32 bit ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, elf

I have createa a sample Opencv C++ ".so" file which will simply display the images passed by opencv Python script (ie., My python script will call the C++ ".so" file and pass a image to it ). The communication between python and C++ is done with Boost library.

I did all this in 64-bit ubuntu machine.Now I need to run my python script which call the ".so" in 32 bit ubuntu machine, where I am getting the below error.

```
cv2.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

This is because of opencv "cv2.so" is expected to be 32 bit? How can I create a 32 bit "cv2.so" in ubuntu 64 bit machine? Also do I need to create my own ".so" file ( which displays the images) as 32 bit?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.  On your `32-bit` Ubuntu machine, you need to make sure that your executable and all its dependencies are `32-bit`. Meaning that you need to re-compile your `.so` in `32-bit` (or get it from a 3rd party).
To compile 32-bit libraries, you need to indicate this to your compiler and linker, most likely with a flag (for instance `-m32` in case of `gcc`)

Comment: cant I compile a 32 bit version in my 64 bit machine with the flag?

Comment: but the problem is with opencv ".so" do I need to build it again as 32 bit so?

Comment: Is there a means to obtain the 32-bit versions of libraries via apt-get, rather than building them manually from sources?